# MS Access query table without primary key

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
Claim# Total ValuationDt
  1     100     1/1/12
  2     550     1/1/12
  1     2000    3/1/12
  2     100     4/1/12
  1     2100    8/1/12
  3     200     8/1/12
  3     250     11/1/12
```

Using MS Access, I need a query that returns only claims which have been valuated greater than $500 at some point in that claim's life time.  In this example, the query should return

```
Claim# Total ValuationDt
  1     100     1/1/12
  2     550     1/1/12
  1     2000    3/1/12
  2     100     4/1/12
  1     2100    8/1/12
```

because claim# 1 was valuated greater than $500 on 3/1/12, claim# 2 was valuated greater than $500 on 1/1/12, and claim# 3 was never valuated greater than $500.

Comment: Why is this tagged ms-access when the title and text say ms sql?

Comment: @Dan Sorry, that stuff always confuses me.  I thought they were the same thing.  I'm showing my inexperience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Claim IN (SELECT Claim
                FROM Table1
                WHERE Total > 500)
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70a7e/2/0)

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
Select DISTINCT Claim FROM yourtable Where Total > 500
```

EDIT:

In the case that my initial answer does not fulfill your requirements, then you can use a sub-query. A subquery is a query inside your query (nested queries). The reason we have to do it like that is because if you use something like

```
Select * FROM yourtable Where Total > 500
```

Then the result set would only be those moments where the total of the claim was higher than 500, but it would not indicate other moments where it was less or equal than 500.

Therefore, as others have stated, you use a subquery like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Claim IN (SELECT Claim
                FROM Table1
                WHERE Total > 500)
```

Note: see that there is a query after the IN keyword, so we have nested queries (or subquery if you prefer).

Why does it work? well, because:

```
SELECT Claim
FROM Table1
WHERE Total > 500
```

Will return every claim (only the number of the claim) in which the total was greater than 500 at some point. Therefore, this query will return 1 and 2.  If you substitute that in the original query you get:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Claim IN (1, 2)
```

Which will get you every column of every row with Claim numbers equal to either 1 or 2.

Comment: this won't see the table in the query should return

Comment: @Photon, Ben said "I need a query that returns only claims", so, I only returned the claim, but I get your point.

Comment: I think you missed the rest "...Which have been valuated greater than $500 a......."

Comment: If this query were used on my sample table, it would not have returned the first row of my sample result.

Comment: @Felipe Okay, your edited query should work. Very thorough btw.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Select * from table where claim in (Select claim from table where total > 500)
```

Here `table` is the name of your table.

Answer (score 2):

**This could be the solution**

```
    SELECT distinct * 
    FROM YourTableName 
    WHERE claim# IN (SELECT DISTINCT claim#
                     FROM YourTableName
                     WHERE total > 500) 
    ORDER BY 3;
```

*Optionally order by*

Answer (score 1):

You can identify which `[Claim#]` values satisfy your condition ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Claim#]
FROM YourTable
WHERE [Total] > 500
```

If that was correct, use it as a subquery which you `INNER JOIN` to your table, to restrict the result set to only those claims.

```
SELECT y.[Claim#], y.[Total], y.[ValidationDt] 
FROM YourTable AS y
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT [Claim#]
            FROM YourTable
            WHERE [Total] > 500
        ) AS sub
    ON y.[Claim#] = sub.[Claim#];
```

Compare this approach vs. the `IN()` suggestions and see whether you notice any difference in execution speed.

Comment: I fully expected this query to perform better than the others, especially since my real table has about 400,000 rows.  However, it turns out that the IN() clause was noticeably faster than this INNER JOIN approach.  Gave you an upVote regardless.

Comment: I would bet the query plan shows the select distinct sort has a negative impact

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
  SELECT [Claim#],[Total],[ValidationDt] 
  FROM yourtable 
  WHERE [Claim#] IN (SELECT [Claim#] 
                     FROM yourtable 
                     WHERE Total >= 500)
```

Should return all values >= 500 for any ValidationDt.